# Bash completely CLI interactive menu

Tags: bash, shell-script, menu

I know there are programs which make a TUI (like `dialog`, `whiptail`) which allow selections in bash. However, I want a simple, nice, completely CLI menu (may not be simple to implement though).

Note:

- the program should **NOT** clear the terminal (it should keep current terminal contents intact)
- the program should change contents of the menu instead of spitting out lines every key input

The answer should be a bash/shell script.

Given an array of strings (4 in this case):

```
options=(opt1 "option 2" another "option here")
```

I want to construct a menu with the selected option highlighted (option will be chosen if pressed `enter`):
[image: Example 1]

If the user presses arrow up/down, the program should select the previous/next item and "cycle" through options (selection becomes last when arrow up is pressed on first option). This example shows the menu after arrow down is pressed:
[image: Example 2]

If the user types "opt", the menu selection should only show options starting with "opt" and change back the current selection to the first item:
[image: Example 3]

Is this even possible? If yes, please tell me how. Also, I am willing to add any description if requested.

Comment: bash has a build in command "select" which behaves quiet similar to your description, but you have to choose by number.

Comment: select name in Frank Fred Francis; do echo Hello $name; break; done

Comment: i think it differs. the `select` command cannot go through options using arrow keys + not interactive

Comment: @sudoer It definitely is _interactive_, only not allowing the user to choose with the arrow keys.

Comment: hmm ok. correct me if i am wrong, but there isnt the filter options by input feature

Comment: using arrow keys and inverse the to-be-selected output would imply redrawing the screen, which can only be done by terminal-escapes. You would have to program this (maybe with "tput" to get the codes) or use a library like ncurses. this is possible (even inside bash), but likely not be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is this tool called [fzy](https://github.com/jhawthorn/fzy), which is a fuzzy finder. The script should be:

```
options=(opt1 "option 2" another "option here")
echo "Please choose an option:"
printf "%s\n" "${options[@]}" | fzy
```

This seems to do what I want.

Comment: Hmm, using a fuzzy finder is great, but its not really what you asked for. Take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1386907/1771279